# Clean Rspec matcher for change(Model, :count).by(1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec2, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm working hard trying to keep my spec files as clean as possible. Using 'shoulda' gem and writing customized matchers that follow the same pattern.

My question is about creating a custom matcher that would wrap `expect{ post :create ... }.to change(Model, :count).by(1)` and could be used in the same example groups with other 'shoulda' matchers. Details bellow:

**Custom matcher (simplified)**

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :create_a_new do |model|
  match do |dummy|
    ::RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationTarget.new(subject).to change(model, :count).by(1)
  end
end
```

**Working example**

```
describe 'POST create:' do
  describe '(valid params)' do
    subject { -> { post :create, model: agency_attributes } }
    it { should create_a_new(Agency) }
  end
end
```

This work OK as long as I use a `subject` lambda and my matcher is the only one in the example group.

**Failing examples**

*Failing example 1*

Adding more examples in the same group makes the other matcher fail because `subject` is now a lambda instead of an instance of the Controller.

```
describe 'POST create:' do
  describe '(valid params)' do
    subject { -> { post :create, model: agency_attributes } }
    it { should create_a_new(Agency) }
    it { should redirect_to(Agency.last) }
  end
end
```

*Failing example 2*

The 'shoulda' matcher expect me to define a `before` block, but this become incompatible with my custom matcher

```
describe 'POST create:' do
  describe '(valid params)' do
    before { post :create, agency: agency_attributes }
    it { should create_a_new(Agency) }
    it { should redirect_to(Agency.last) }
  end
end
```

**Expected result**

I am looking for a way to write my custom matcher that would fit in the same example group as other matchers, meaning my custom matcher should use the `before` block to execute the controller action, the "failing example #2" above is the way I would like to write my specs. Is it possible?

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do not think there is a way you can get your failing examples passing.

This is because `change` really needs a lambda, since it needs to perform your count twice (once before, and once after calling it). That's the reason I tend not to use it (or use it in context isolation).

What I usually do, instead of using the `count` matcher, is checking three things:

- The record is persisted. If I assign the model to `@model`, then I use `expect(assigns(:model)).to be_persisted`
- The record is an instance of the expected model (though might not seem useful, it is
  quite descriptive when using an STI). `expect(assigns(:model)).to be_a(Model)`.
- Check the last record in DB is the same as the one I just create `expect(assigns(:model)).to eq(Model.last)``

And that's the way I usually test the `change` matcher without using it. Of course, you can now create your own matcher

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :create_a_new do |model|
  match do |actual|
    actual.persisted? &&
      actual.instance_of?(Participant) &&
      (Participant.last == actual)
  end
end
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the clarification. Let me test this a bit and I'll be back with you.

Comment: Another thing I am trying lately is encapsulating the action (`post :create, params, session`) in a method. Not sure yet if I'll keep doing it, but for some cases, it might be worth it.

Comment: That was one of my tries as well `set(:action) {post :create ...}` but I did not find a way to be really DRY, because I ended up with smelly code like `before { unless example.metadata[:skip_before]; action end }`

Comment: There is a way with `around` hooks, but that would imply running the expectation in each example, and I don't think it is what you want.

Comment: Sorry for taking my time to answer, I haven't checked yet but it seems the right thing to do, I'll test it later whenever I find time to do so. Thanks for the tip